# Número em extenso para número

Tags: c#, string, inteiros

Gostaria de transformar um numero extenso para int normal; exemplo:

```
FunçãoParaConverter("trinta e dois")                        // retorna 32
FunçãoParaConverter("mil vinte e quatro")                   // retorna 1024
FunçãoParaConverter("mil trezentos e trinta e tres")        // retorna 1333
FunçãoParaConverter("sete mil setecentos e setenta e sete") // retorna 7777
```

Comment: Tem um exemplo em Python [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493788/6241184) e um em C# [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171816/6241184). Mas a implementação em português é diferente, claro.

Comment: só vai ter que adicionar os tratamentos para os plurais: milhões, bilhões e etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com base nos exemplos listados nos comentários da pergunta, eu criei a rotina abaixo para converter o número por extenso em `int`.

Resumidamente, a rotina funciona da seguinte forma: ela quebra o texto por extenso em palavras e busca nos dicionários (`NumDict` e `MilharDict`) o valor que será contabilizado para cada palavra.

Ela está funcionando direitinho mas pode ser melhorada. Por exemplo: poderia ser implementada uma verificação de sintaxe do texto para gerar um erro quando o texto estivesse escrito errado (ex: trinta e dez)

Um exemplo do código rodando online em https://ideone.com/vWGJYQ (by @VirgilioNovic)

```
Dictionary<string,int> NumDict;
Dictionary<string,int> MilharDict;

private int ExtensoToInteiro(string extenso)
{           

    if (NumDict == null)
    {
        NumDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        MilharDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

        NumDict.Add("zero",0);
        NumDict.Add("um",1);
        NumDict.Add("dois",2);
        NumDict.Add("três",3);
        NumDict.Add("quatro",4);
        NumDict.Add("cinco",5);
        NumDict.Add("seis",6);
        NumDict.Add("sete",7);
        NumDict.Add("oito",8);
        NumDict.Add("nove",9);

        NumDict.Add("dez",10);
        NumDict.Add("onze",11);
        NumDict.Add("doze",12);
        NumDict.Add("treze",13);
        NumDict.Add("quatorze",14);
        NumDict.Add("quinze",15);
        NumDict.Add("dezesseis",16);
        NumDict.Add("dezessete",17);
        NumDict.Add("dezoito",18);
        NumDict.Add("dezenove",19);

        NumDict.Add("vinte",20);
        NumDict.Add("trinta",30);
        NumDict.Add("quarenta",40);
        NumDict.Add("cinquenta",50);
        NumDict.Add("sessenta",60);
        NumDict.Add("setenta",70);
        NumDict.Add("oitenta",80);
        NumDict.Add("noventa",90);

        NumDict.Add("cem",100);
        NumDict.Add("cento",100); 
        NumDict.Add("duzentos",200);
        NumDict.Add("trezentos",300);
        NumDict.Add("quatrocentos",400);
        NumDict.Add("quinhentos",500);
        NumDict.Add("seiscentos",600);
        NumDict.Add("setecentos",700);
        NumDict.Add("oitocentos",800);
        NumDict.Add("novecentos",900);

        MilharDict.Add("mil",1000);
        MilharDict.Add("milhão",1000000);
        MilharDict.Add("milhões",1000000);
        MilharDict.Add("bilhão",1000000000);
        MilharDict.Add("bilhões",1000000000);
    }

    int resultado = 0;
    int grupoCorrente = 0;

    foreach (var word in extenso.Split(' '))
    {
        if (NumDict.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            grupoCorrente += NumDict[word];
        }
        else if (MilharDict.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            resultado += (grupoCorrente == 0 ? 1 : grupoCorrente) * MilharDict[word];
            grupoCorrente = 0;
        }               
    }

    resultado += grupoCorrente;

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Um exemplo do código rodando online https://ideone.com/vWGJYQ

Comment: Muito bom @VirgilioNovic! Adicionei seu exemplo à resposta.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><title>teste✏️</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<body style="text-align:center;"
<head>
        <style>
    
       body {
  display:flex; flex-direction:line; justify-content:center;
  min-height:20vh;
   font-size: 150%;
}

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function replaceToNum() {
  var Small = { 
   'zero': 0,
  'um': 1,
  'dois': 2,
  'três': 3,
  'quatro': 4,
  'cinco': 5,
  'seis': 6,
  'sete': 7,
  'oito': 8,
  'nove': 9,
  'dez': 10,
  'onze': 11,
  'doze': 12,
  'treze': 13,
  'quatorze': 14,
  'quinze': 15,
  'dezesseis': 16,
  'dezessete': 17,
  'dezoito': 18,
  'dezenove': 19,
  'vinte': 20,
  'trinta': 30,
  'quarenta': 40,
  'cinquenta': 50,
  'sessenta': 60,
  'setenta': 70,
  'oitenta': 80,
  'noventa': 90,
  'cento': 100,
   'duzentos': 200,
    'trezentos': 300,
     'quatrocentos': 400,
      'quinhentos': 500,
       'seiscentos': 600,
        'setecentos': 700,
         'oitocentos': 800,
          'novecentos': 900,
};

var med = {
  'mil': 1000,
  'milhão': 1000000,
  'bilhão': 1000000000,
  'trilhão': 1000000000000,
  'quadrilhão': 1000000000000000,
  'quintilhão': 1000000000000000000,
  'sextilhão': 1000000000000000000000,
  'septilhão': 1000000000000000000000000,
  'octilhão': 1000000000000000000000000000,
  'nonilhão': 1000000000000000000000000000000,
  'decilhão': 1000000000000000000000000000000000,
};
  var a, n, g;
  function text2num(s) {
    a = s.toString().split(/[\s-]+/); n = 0; g = 0;
    a.forEach(feach);
    return g + n;
  }
  function feach(w) {
    var x = Small[w];
    if (x != null) {
      g = g + x;
    } else if (w == "hundred") {
      g = g * 100;
    } else if (w == "e") {
      return;
    } else {
      x = med[w];
      if (x != null) {
        n = n + g * x
        g = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  var words = "(" + Object.keys(med).join('|') + "|e|hundred|" + Object.keys(Small).join('|') + ")+( |-)*" + "(" + Object.keys(med).join('|') + "|e|-|hundred| |" + Object.keys(Small).join('|') + ")*( |[.,^~`´])";
  var regex = new RegExp(words, 'gim');
  text = text.toString() + " ";
  text.match(regex).forEach(function(el, i) {
    text = text.replace(el.replace(/\s$/g, '').replace(/[.,^~`´]/g, ''), text2num(el.replace(/[.,^~`´]/g, '').toLowerCase()));
  })
  return text;
}
var text = " R$ dez milhão duzentos e quarenta e dois mil e quatrocentos e vinte e um, e dez";
var total= text;
document.body.innerHTML += "<br><br>";
document.body.innerHTML += replaceToNum(); '&'

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Brasileirando a escrita dos números.

Comment: Brasileirando a forma de escrita de números.