# Como converter um número em valor monetário por extenso em Python?

Tags: python, valor-monetário

Existe alguma função built-in ou biblioteca que realize a conversão de um número em um valor monetário por extenso em Python?

Comment: O propóstio desse site não é que as pessoas façam programas para você, e sim, responder a perguntas sobre programação - 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jsbueno não vejo a pergunta como de todo mal, aliais vi perguntas semelhantes https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99460/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263365/3635, o que acho que .... Claro que em parte concordo contigo, não pelos mesmos motivos, mas sim no sentido que a pergunta basicamente já tem respostas no site, em outras linguagens, mas se tratando de algorítimo bastaria adaptar. O que valeria uma duplicata, claro que teria que juntar umas duas perguntas, algo para converter o monetário em um numero e outra para falar sobre o extenso.

Comment: @JsBueno não é um program inteiro, é só uma orientação de duas linhas:  `>>>import locale`    `>>>valueDecimal = locale.atof(valueCurrency[1:])`. Quando assim o importante não é responder e sim dar um rumo.

Comment: Publiquei e respondi a pergunta. Ao procurar encontrei varias perguntas semelhantes mas dependiam de um dicionário para cada numero e sua respectiva descrição.

Answer (score 4):

Pode-se utilizar [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) com o parâmetro `lang=pt_BR` para obter um número inteiro por extenso. Um exemplo que inclui o formato e a adição de centavo(s) ou real(ais) na string retornada:

```
from num2words import num2words

def number_to_long_number(number_p):
    if number_p.find(',')!=-1:
        number_p = number_p.split(',')
        number_p1 = int(number_p[0].replace('.',''))
        number_p2 = int(number_p[1])
    else:
        number_p1 = int(number_p.replace('.',''))
        number_p2 = 0    
        
    if number_p1 == 1:
        aux1 = ' real'
    else:
        aux1 = ' reais'
        
    if number_p2 == 1:
        aux2 = ' centavo'
    else:
        aux2 = ' centavos'
        
    text1 = ''
    if number_p1 > 0:
        text1 = num2words(number_p1,lang='pt_BR') + str(aux1)
    else:
        text1 = ''
    
    if number_p2 > 0:
        text2 = num2words(number_p2,lang='pt_BR') + str(aux2) 
    else: 
        text2 = ''
    
    if (number_p1 > 0 and number_p2 > 0):
        result = text1 + ' e ' + text2
    else:
        result = text1 + text2

    return result
```

[image: Exemplo de retorno]

Comment: A própria num2words já possui esse recurso, usando apenas o parâmetro "to":  `num2words(12345.22, lang='pt_BR', to="currency")`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um dicionário onde a chave será o número e o valor ser o número por extenso.

```
numero = {1:'um', 2:'dois', 3:'três'}

print(numero.get(1))
print(numero.get(2))
print(numero.get(3))
```

Saída:

```
um
dois
três
```