# Como ignorar uma vírgula dentro de uma string no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, galera! Eu tô fazendo um programa que receba um **número em extenso** e o converta para **numérico**. Para isso, eu preciso ignorar quando um usuário digitar "e" ou vírgula. Por exemplo: Se ele digitar **"mil, quinhentos e quinze"**, o valor retornado deverá ser **1515**. Consegui ignorar o "e" com sucesso, porém a vírgula só é ignorada caso esteja separada da palavra, como **"mil , quinhentos e quinze"**. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tô usando dois arquivos: o index.js e o w2n.js

Arquivo w2n.js:

```
const w2n = require('./index');
const num = process.argv[2];

console.log(w2n.toNum(num));
```

Arquivo index.js: ***Obs: O código está incompleto, relevem os comentários***

```
const table = [
    [ '', 'zero', 'um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove'],
    [ '', 'onze', 'doze', 'treze', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'dezesseis', 'dezessete', 'dezoito', 'dezenove']
    [ '', 'dez', 'vinte', 'trinta', 'quarenta', 'cinquenta', 'sessenta', 'setenta', 'oitenta', 'noventa'],
    [ '', 'cem', 'cento', 'duzentos', 'trezentos', 'quatrocentos', 'quinhentos', 'seiscentos', 'oitocentos', 'novecentos'],
    [ '', 'mil', 'milhão', 'bilhão', 'trilhão', 'quatrilhão', 'quadrilhão', 'quintilhão', 'sextilhão', 'septilhão', 'octilhão', 'nonilhão', 'decilhão'],
    [ '', 'milhões', 'bilhões', 'trilhões', 'quadrilhões', 'quintilhões', 'sextilhões', 'septilhões', 'octilhões', 'nonilhões', 'decilhões']
];

const s2v = {
    'zero':            0,
    'um':              1,
    'dois':            2,
    'três':            3,
    'quatro':          4,
    'cinco':           5,
    'seis':            6,
    'sete':            7,
    'oito':            8,
    'nove':            9,
    'dez':             10,
    'onze':            11,
    'doze':            12,
    'treze':           13,
    'quatorze':        14,
    'quinze':          15,
    'dezesseis':       16,
    'dezessete':       17,
    'dezoito':         18,
    'dezenove':        19,
    'vinte':           20,
    'trinta':          30,
    'quarenta':        40,
    'cinquenta':       50,
    'sessenta':        60,
    'setenta':         70,
    'oitenta':         80,
    'noventa':         90,
    'cem':             100,
    'cento':           100,
    'duzentos':        200,
    'trezentos':       300,
    'quatrocentos':    400,
    'quinhentos':      500,
    'seiscentos':      600,
    'setecentos':      700,
    'oitocentos':      800,
    'novecentos':      900,
    'mil':             1000,
    'milhão':          1000000,
    'bilhão':          1000000000,
    'trilhão':         1000000000000,
    'quatrilhão':      1000000000000000,
    'quadrilhão':      1000000000000000,
    'quintilhão':      1000000000000000000n, //a partir do quintilhão, as variáveis estão em BigInt, representado pelo "n" no final
    'sextilhão':       1000000000000000000000n, //porém, o código não funciona a partir desse ponto
    'septilhão':       1000000000000000000000000n, //erro no: result = result + v;
    'octilhão':        1000000000000000000000000000n,
    'nonilhão':        1000000000000000000000000000000n,
    'decilhão':        1000000000000000000000000000000000n
};

function toNum(num) {
    let result = 0;
    let previous = 0;
    const digits = (num + '').split(' ');

    for (digit of digits) {
        switch (digit) {
            case 'e':
            case ',': //se a vírgula estiver junta com a palavra, o código não funciona
                break;
            default:
                const i = Object.keys(s2v).indexOf(digit);
                const v = Object.values(s2v)[i];
                result = result + v; //não processa valores BigInt
                //previous = v;
                if (i < 0) throw 'ERRO! Número não reconhecido.'
        }
    }
    return result;
}

module.exports = {toNum};
```

Comment: Fazer um "replace" nestes elementos no começo da função não resolve?

Comment: Um detalhe é que vc não pode misturar números inteiros com `BigInt`, por isso dá erro a partir do quintilhão...

Comment: A pergunta indicada acima no box azul tem [uma resposta em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/552501/112052), creio que basta adaptar para o seu caso (por exemplo, trocando tudo para `BigInt` para resolver o problema que já mencionei acima)

Comment: Em vez de se preocupar em eliminar a vírgula, pode fazer o contrário e pegar uma sequência de várias letras. Além disso, tem que diferenciar o valor da ordem de grandeza (por exemplo, em "quinze mil, trezentos e dois", tem 2 grupos: "quinze mil" (o valor 15 e ordem de grandeza 1000), e "trezentos e dois" (valor 302, ordem de grandeza 1)). Assim vc consegue fazer a conta correta: https://ideone.com/xW61Cz

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Você precisa limpar a string retirando os caracteres que não vai usar (a vírgula e o `e` (com os espaços)).  Para isso, pode utilizar o `replaceAll` que subistituirá todas as ocorrências por outra string. No seu caso, por espaço.

```js
const table = [
    [ '', 'zero', 'um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove'],
    [ '', 'onze', 'doze', 'treze', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'dezesseis', 'dezessete', 'dezoito', 'dezenove']
    [ '', 'dez', 'vinte', 'trinta', 'quarenta', 'cinquenta', 'sessenta', 'setenta', 'oitenta', 'noventa'],
    [ '', 'cem', 'cento', 'duzentos', 'trezentos', 'quatrocentos', 'quinhentos', 'seiscentos', 'oitocentos', 'novecentos'],
    [ '', 'mil', 'milhão', 'bilhão', 'trilhão', 'quatrilhão', 'quadrilhão', 'quintilhão', 'sextilhão', 'septilhão', 'octilhão', 'nonilhão', 'decilhão'],
    [ '', 'milhões', 'bilhões', 'trilhões', 'quadrilhões', 'quintilhões', 'sextilhões', 'septilhões', 'octilhões', 'nonilhões', 'decilhões']
];

const s2v = {
    'zero':            0,
    'um':              1,
    'dois':            2,
    'três':            3,
    'quatro':          4,
    'cinco':           5,
    'seis':            6,
    'sete':            7,
    'oito':            8,
    'nove':            9,
    'dez':             10,
    'onze':            11,
    'doze':            12,
    'treze':           13,
    'quatorze':        14,
    'quinze':          15,
    'dezesseis':       16,
    'dezessete':       17,
    'dezoito':         18,
    'dezenove':        19,
    'vinte':           20,
    'trinta':          30,
    'quarenta':        40,
    'cinquenta':       50,
    'sessenta':        60,
    'setenta':         70,
    'oitenta':         80,
    'noventa':         90,
    'cem':             100,
    'cento':           100,
    'duzentos':        200,
    'trezentos':       300,
    'quatrocentos':    400,
    'quinhentos':      500,
    'seiscentos':      600,
    'setecentos':      700,
    'oitocentos':      800,
    'novecentos':      900,
    'mil':             1000,
    'milhão':          1000000,
    'bilhão':          1000000000,
    'trilhão':         1000000000000,
    'quatrilhão':      1000000000000000,
    'quadrilhão':      1000000000000000,
    'quintilhão':      1000000000000000000n, //a partir do quintilhão, as variáveis estão em BigInt, representado pelo "n" no final
    'sextilhão':       1000000000000000000000n, //porém, o código não funciona a partir desse ponto
    'septilhão':       1000000000000000000000000n, //erro no: result = result + v;
    'octilhão':        1000000000000000000000000000n,
    'nonilhão':        1000000000000000000000000000000n,
    'decilhão':        1000000000000000000000000000000000n
};

function toNum(num) {
    let result = 0;
    let previous = 0;
    //Limpando a ',' e o ' e '
    numLimpo = num.replaceAll(',','').replaceAll(' e ', ' ');        
    const digits = (numLimpo + '').split(' ');

    for (digit of digits) {
        const i = Object.keys(s2v).indexOf(digit);
        const v = Object.values(s2v)[i];
        result = result + v; //não processa valores BigInt
        //previous = v;
        if (i < 0) throw `ERRO! Número '${digit}' não reconhecido.`
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(toNum("mil, duzentos e vinte e três"))
console.log(toNum("quatrocentos e vinte e dois"))
```

Comment: Uma observação, com o `replaceAll`, o `switch` não é mais necessário, nunca vai cair nos `case`, sempre será e executado o `default`

Comment: Um outro detalhe que vale mencionar, é que `replaceAll` é suportado a partir da versão [v15.0.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility) do Node.js, apesar de não ser mencionado na pergunta, vale a atenção. Uma alternativa seria usar o `replace` com uma regex global para remover esses elementos. `.replace(/\se\s/g, ' ').replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: Também dá pra fazer em um único `replace`, por exemplo: `.replace(/,|\be\b/g, '')`. Mas ainda tem outro problema, que é misturar `BigInt` com inteiros (por exemplo, "um octilhão e três" vai dar erro por misturar esses tipos)

Comment: @hkotsubo gerou uma string vazia no array e ocasionou um erro... :|

Comment: @CmteCardeal Está falando somente do `replace`?

Comment: o fluxo total do script. Mas um `filter(Boolean)` resolve :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @LucasTeixeira Ainda tem o problema de misturar `BigInt` com inteiros (teste com "um quintilhão e dois", por exemplo). Na verdade ainda não funciona para vários casos (teste com "quinze mil", por exemplo)

Comment: @hkotsubo na verdade esse é outro problema que preciso ajustar, porém preferi não mencionar na pergunta, pra dúvida da vírgula ficar mais clara. O código tá funcionando perfeitamente do 0 até 1999, porém se eu coloco "dois mil", ele retorna 1002, por exemplo. Tô tentando achar uma solução aqui e até pretendo realizar uma outra pergunta depois.

Comment: @LucasTeixeira  Outra sugestão: em vez de focar no que não se quer (a vírgula e o "e"), pode fazer o contrário e focar no que quer (sequência de duas ou mais letras). Ou seja, em vez de `replace` e `split`, use `match(/[a-zãêõ]{2,}/g)` - assim ele pega duas ou mais letras, automaticamente ignorando o "e" e a vírgula. Algo assim: https://ideone.com/g4uevt